# Visual Studio 2013 Bypass Authentication When Debugging

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.Net website that uses authentication. In VS2012 I simply commented out:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

to debug without having to login.

However, I've now opened the site in VS2013 and I get an access denied error when I hit debug. What can I do to bypass authentication whilst debugging in VS2013?

Answer (score 0):

I've got around the issue by commenting out

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="administrator" />
  <deny users="xxx1" />
  <deny roles="xxx2" />
  <deny roles="xxx3" />
  <deny roles="xxx4" />
  <deny roles="xxx5" />
</authorization>
```

in web.config.

Thought I's share if anyone else get's caught out.